# Child List Element Gets Only 1 Record in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

In Entity Framework, I would like to get one object which includes a list, but list gets only first record.

I have 2 objects Sale and Profile, they are different from database objects, I create these objects in query like "select new Sale { }". Profile object contains Sale type list. When query executed, list gets just first record in database.

**Sale Complex Object**

```
public class Sale
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Header { get; set; }
  public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Profile Complex Object**

```
public class Profile
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Sale> SalesList { get; set; }
}
```

I use left join because it should insert this object to list, if next object is null.

**Query Here**

```
Profile profile = (from u in db.USER
                   join s in db.SALE on u.ID equals s.USER_ID into saleleft
                   from salej in saleleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where u.ID == _userId
                   select new Profile
                   {
                      Id = u.ID,
                      Name = u.NAME,
                      SalesList= new List<Sale>()
                      {
                          salej != null ? new Sale
                          {
                             Id=postj.ID,                                            
                             Header=salej.HEADER,
                             Price=salej.PRICE                                           
                          } : null
                      }.ToList()
                   }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I guess this can be about FirstOrDefault() method. Hence I think it should get all records to SalesList. How can I get all records to list? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you created a list with only one element

Comment: I researched about how child list can be filled in complex type. Therefore I used this way. How can I change my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `group` here. Could you try this and let me know if it works?

```
// didn't test the code
Profile profile = (from u in db.USER
               join s in db.SALE on u.ID equals s.USER_ID into saleleft
               where u.ID == _userId

               from salej in saleleft.DefaultIfEmpty()
               group salej by new { u.ID, u.NAME } into g

               select new Profile
               {
                  Id = g.Key.ID,
                  Name = g.Key.NAME,
                  SalesList = g.Select( x => new Sale { Id = postj.ID, Header = x.HEADER, Price = x.PRICE }).ToList()
               }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Btw, what is `postj`?